# Get Sum of Values using array_combine?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to count the total sum of values using array_combine. I have the duplicate key also, for example i have the array of emailid and  array of product price.

```
$data1 = array("email1@example.com","email2@example.com","email1@example.com");
```

and `$data2 = array("100","200","300");`

Now in `$data1` i have two duplicate values as email1@example.com

I am trying to use `array_combine()` It ignore the duplicate values and add the new one

I get this result as

```
email1@example.com => 300;
email2@example.com => 200;
```

But i want the result should be

```
email1@example.com => (400)100+300;
email2@example.com => 200;
```

Not sure how to get this result with `array_combine` Is something any alternatives to achieve this ?

Any Suggestion would be great.

Comment: `array_combine` simply won't help you here. It's trivial if you write a manual loop though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a simple loop:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($data1 as $i => $v) {
  if (!isset($result[$v])) {
     $result[$v] = 0;
  }
  $result[$v] += $data2[$i];
}
```